# How can I reorder my UINavigationController items programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my TabBarViewController, I'm creating a navigation and presenting it modally.

```
func viewDidLoad(){ 
    super.viewDidLoad();
    //Create a present this view controller in viewDidLoad
    self.navController =  UINavigationController() 
    self.presentViewController(self.navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//This method gets called when TabBarVC gets a NSNotification
func showMessageForUser(user_id: Int){
    let mvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
    mvc.user_id = user_id //set this user

    //display this to the user.
    self.navController.pushViewController(mvc, animated: true)
}
```

This is pretty straight forward. However, I would like to do this:

- If the user_id is ***already*** in the stack, move it to the end of the stack so that it's visible to the user. No duplicates.  How can I do this?
- Else, just create a new instance of the view controller and add it to the top of the stack. I think I'm already doing this above.

All the "back" buttons should work as expected after reordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` to rearrange the view controller stack. You don't have to do anything special to make the back button work correctly. The navigation controller sets up the back button based on the second item in its `viewControllers` array (if there is a second item), and updates the back button whenever it updates the `viewControllers` array.

Here's how I'd do this. First, we add a method to `UIViewController` to ask whether it's the view controller for a specific `userId`. Since most view controllers are not (and cannot be) the correct view controller, it just returns `false`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func isViewControllerForUserId(userId: Int) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Then we override this method in `MessagesViewController` to return `true` when appropriate:

```
extension MessagesViewController {
    override func isViewControllerForUserId(userId: Int) -> Bool {
        return self.userId == userId
    }
}
```

Now, to show the view controller for a specific user, we search the navigation controller's stack for an existing view controller. The action we take depends on whether we find it:

```
func showMessageForUserId(userId: Int) {
    if let index = navController.viewControllers.indexOf({ $0.isViewControllerForUserId(userId) }) {
        navController.moveToTopOfNavigationStack(viewControllerAtIndex: index)
    } else {
        pushNewViewControllerForUserId(userId)
    }
}
```

If we didn't find it, we make a new view controller and push it:

```
    private func pushNewViewControllerForUserId(userId: Int) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
        vc.userId = userId
        self.navController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

If we did find it, we move it to the top of the navigation stack with this method:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func moveToTopOfNavigationStack(viewControllerAtIndex index: Int) {
        var stack = viewControllers
        if index == stack.count - 1 {
            // nothing to do because it's already on top
            return
        }
        let vc = stack.removeAtIndex(index)
        if (reorderingIsBuggy) {
            setViewControllers(stack, animated: false)
        }
        stack.append(vc)
        setViewControllers(stack, animated: true)
    }

    private var reorderingIsBuggy: Bool {
        // As of iOS 9.3 beta 3, `UINavigationController` drops the prior top-of-stack
        // when you use `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` to move a lower item to the
        // top with animation. The workaround is to remove the lower item from the stack
        // without animation, then add it to the top of the stack with animation. This
        // makes it display a push animation instead of a pop animation and avoids
        // dropping the prior top-of-stack.
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I printed the stack after removing it at the index and appending it.  It printed in the correct order, so it looks fine. When I call ```setViewControllers```, everything seems fine and desired VC gets shown to the top. However, the VC before it gets ```deinit``` and disappears. Do you know why the previous VC disappears? (I'm only testing on 2 VCs)

Comment: Note: I changed this line: ```navController.setViewControllers(stack, animated: false)``` to animated: false, and all seems to work fine. Any idea why making this change solved the problem?

Comment: Which view controller runs `deinit`?

Comment: When testing on 2 VCs, the one that *isn't* the top gets deinit.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work around the `UINavigationController` bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method showMessageForUser(_:), replace yours with this, works like a charm..

```
func showMessageForUser(user_id: Int){
    var mvcItem: MessagesViewController?
    var controllers: [UIViewController] = (self.navController?.viewControllers)!

    var matchindex: Int? = -1
    for (index, viewItem) in controllers.enumerate() {
        if (viewItem is MessagesViewController) {

            if viewItem.user_id == user_id {
                matchindex = index
                break
            }
        }
    }

    if matchindex != -1 {       //jus making sure a matching index was found
        mvcItem = (controllers.removeAtIndex(matchindex!)) as? MessagesViewController
    }

    if mvcItem != nil {
        self.navController?.viewControllers = controllers
        self.navController?.pushViewController(mvcItem!, animated: true)
    } else {
        let mvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
        mvc.user_id = user_id //set this user

        //display this to the user.
        self.navController.pushViewController(mvc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make the code easier to reason about I'd create your own UINavigationController.

Something like this:

```
final class MessagesNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // Option 1: If you want to dismiss everything that was in the midle, you can just do this:
    func showMessageForUser(user_id: Int){
        guard let messagesViewController = findMessagesViewController(withUserId: user_id) else {
            let mvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
            mvc.user_id = user_id
            pushViewController(mvc, animated: true)
            return
        }

        popToViewController(messagesViewController, animated: false)

    }

    private func findMessagesViewController(withUserId userId: Int) -> MessagesViewController? {
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            guard let messagesViewController = viewController as? MessagesViewController
                where messagesViewController.user_id == userId else { continue }
            return messagesViewController

        }
        return nil
    }

    // Option 2: If you want to move the viewcontroller from the position it currently is, to the end
    // but keeping everything in the middle, you can do this:
    func showMessageForUser2(user_id: Int){
        guard let index = findMessagesViewControllerIndex(withUserId: user_id) else {
            let mvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
            mvc.user_id = user_id
            pushViewController(mvc, animated: true)
            return
        }

        // This is the main change
        let viewController = viewControllers.removeAtIndex(index)
        pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
    }

    private func findMessagesViewControllerIndex(withUserId userId: Int) -> Int? {
        for (index, viewController) in viewControllers.enumerate() {
            guard let messagesViewController = viewController as? MessagesViewController
                where messagesViewController.user_id == userId else { continue }
            return index

        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

So your TabBarController would look something like this:

```
var navController: MessagesNavigationController!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad();

    navController = MessagesNavigationController()
    presentViewController(self.navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showMessageForUser(user_id: Int){
    navController.showMessageForUser(user_id)
}
```